# Psycopg2 Insert into table two values from another table with a where conditional

Tags: sql-insert, psycopg2

Apologies for the simple question I am new to using PostgreSQL and Psycopg2. I have two columns in  a table I am trying to populate using values from two other tables based on a where conditional. Example code below:

```
    cur = con.cursor()

    db_insert = """INSERT INTO "Database"."TABLE_ONE"
    ("LT_ID_ONE", "LT_ID_TWO")  
    VALUES(
    (SELECT "LT_ID_ONE" FROM "Database"."TABLE_TWO" WHERE "LT_NUM_ONE" =%s), 
    (SELECT "LT_ID_TWO" FROM "Database"."TABLE_THREE" WHERE "LT_NUM_TWO" =%s)
    );"""
    insert_values = (df1.iloc[0, 0], df1.iloc[0, 1])

    cur.execute(db_insert, insert_values)
```

When running this command I receive the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "LOT_ID_ONE" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes the value in DF1 does exist in TABLE_TWO.LT_ID_ONE.  This is one of the first things I checked for.  I assumed I was entering the LT_ID_ONE incorrectly but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: You need to set a value for `LOT_ID_ONE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as though my error was in the order of the elements for the insert_values variable.  Once I swapped them it worked.  So the SQL code I have is correct.